# cmake3 keeps using old CXXFLAGS value

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build the azure storage sdk and have hit a build failure. Looking at the build commands, I see that it is trying to use an old CXXFLAGS value (not sure if this is the reason for the failure but would like to clean this up).

My steps were essentially:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"
run cmake3 and make on cpprestsdk
unset CXXFLAGS
run cmake3 on azure-storage-cpp
```

Then when I look at my `compile_commands.json` file, I still see the -fPIC option being used. I tried deleting the directory and cloning again but it is still there.

CXXFLAGS is not set anymore, even tried using a new shell but still no luck:

```
$ echo $CXXFLAGS
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Edit:
I'm using the following command:

```
cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

and am following CentOS instructions from https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp

Comment: Does the project add `-fPIC` on its own?  Are you building shared objects, in which case `-fPIC` is required (and will be added by cmake)?

Comment: Thanks @StephenNewell The project doesn't add -fPIC. I am building shared libs of azure-storage-cpp which is using static cpprestsdk. So since I am using shared lib cmake is going to automatically add this flag?

Comment: After changing `CXXFLAGS` environment variable make sure that you have deleted the **build** directory (or delete a file `CMakeCache.txt` from that directory). BTW, setting `-fPIC` flag via CXXFLAGS variable is a bad idea.